# WebGLSync is always UNSIGNALED

Tags: javascript, webgl2

I'm trying to play around with [WebGLSyncs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLSync) and I'm having a hard time getting a WebGLSync to be signaled.

The following is unsignaled on all browsers supporting WebGL2 (Chrome, Opera, Firefox):

```
function test() {
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
    let sync = gl.fenceSync(gl.SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
    gl.flush();
    gl.finish();

    let status = gl.getSyncParameter(sync, gl.SYNC_STATUS);
    console.log(sync, status, status === gl.UNSIGNALED);  // logs "true"
    gl.deleteSync(sync);
}
```

I'm expecting this to work, since gl.finish() should wait until all GPU commands have been processed - but it looks like the sync fence was not.

I would very much appreciate a minimal, working `WebGLSync` example that actually gets signaled. I searched GitHub for such but I found nothing.

---

**EDIT**

Based on the [answer from pleup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53647609/2946480), I put together this code sample which works fine in my environment (Windows + Chrome).

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function test() {
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
    let sync = gl.fenceSync(gl.SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
    gl.flush();

    while (gl.getSyncParameter(sync, gl.SYNC_STATUS) === gl.UNSIGNALED) {
        await sleep(100);
    }

    let status = gl.getSyncParameter(sync, gl.SYNC_STATUS);
    console.log(sync, status, status === gl.SIGNALED);
    gl.deleteSync(sync);
}

test()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wait for a tick to see the sync signaled. The sync status will never change during JS execution frame.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#3.7.14

> In order to ensure consistent behavior across platforms, sync objects may only transition to the signaled state when the user agent's event loop is not executing a task. In other words:
>
> A sync object must not become signaled until control has returned to the user agent's main loop.
> Repeatedly fetching a sync object's SYNC_STATUS parameter in a loop, without returning control to the user agent, must always return the same value.

Answer (score 2):

from [the WebGL2 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#5.39)

> 5.39 Sync objects' results must not be made available in the current frame
>   In OpenGL ES 3.0, if the appropriate primitives (e.g. glFinish() or another synchronous API) are called, a sync object may be signaled in the same frame it was issued. In WebGL, in order to improve application portability, a sync object must never transition to the signaled state in the same frame the sync was issued. See the specification of [getSyncParameter](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#GET_SYNC_PARAMETER) and [clientWaitSync](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#CLIENT_WAIT_SYNC) for discussion and rationale.

```js
async function test() {
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
    let sync = gl.fenceSync(gl.SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
    gl.flush();
    gl.finish();

    await waitFrame();

    let status = gl.getSyncParameter(sync, gl.SYNC_STATUS);
    console.log(sync, glEnumToString(gl, status));
    gl.deleteSync(sync);
}

function waitFrame() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    requestAnimationFrame(resolve);
  });
}

function glEnumToString(gl, v) {
  for (const k in gl) {
    if (gl[k] === v) {
      return k;
    }
  }
  return `0x${v.toString(16)}`;
}

test();
```

Comment: For some reason, this yields `UNSIGNALED` for me (both when copied to the browser console and when using "Run code snipped")

Comment: try waiting 2 frames? what browser? what gpu? what os? I tried it in Chrome and FF on Windows 10 with NVidia 1060 and also Chrome and FF on 2014 Macbook Pro. Try the conformance test? https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance2/sync/sync-webgl-specific.html?webglVersion=2&quiet=0